# Passport-google-oauth-20 not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-console-developer, passport-google-oauth2

As it is written in all solutions I added

> proxy: true

, but it changed nothing.

In google console developers I added both http and https, to be sure that everything is working.

```
new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
        proxy: true,
        passport: true,
      },
```

Here's my console developers console:
[image: Here's my console developers console]

And the error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Typo error:
My page was :

> js-apollo-codgen

not

> js-apollo-codegen